# EditorTemplate not rendering as expected?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc-editor-templates

I have a requirement to be able to dynamically add/remove rows to a Tabel in an MVC 5 Application I am working on.  I have also included knockout in my project as I use it to post back to preform calculation on my viewModel.

What I have done so far is created a List on my User Model to hold the details of the AdditionalUsers:

```
public List<AdditionalUser> AdditionalUsers { get; set; }
```

Additional User class defined as:

```
public class AdditionalUser
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public double Cost { get; set; }
}
```

I then created a EditorTemplates folder and created a partial view _AdditionalUser.cshtml as below:

```
@model MyProject.Models.AdditionalUser

<td>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Surname)
</td>
<td>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Cost)
</td>
```

Where I need this rendered on my User View I have done the following:

```
        <tr>
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdditionalUsers)
        </tr>
```

Each other  on the view has 3 .  Doing this then in my controller where I new my User model I did:

```
model.AdditionalUsers =  new List<AdditionalUser>(2);
```

I would have thought that would have created two blank rows in the tr where I called EditorFor but nothing is rendered?  This was just for my first test to get the EditorTemplate working.  I want to then wire this up to knockout to Add and remove the rows dynamically but first I am wondering why the EditorTemplate is not rendering as expected?

Comment: Shouldn't the template be called `AdditionalUser.cshtml` (i.e. remove the underscore prefix)?

Comment: @DavidG - can try that - I had created it as a Partial so had used the _naming convention - so for EditorTemplates I guess should be just regular views?

Comment: Worth remembering that there isn't really such a thing as a partial view. any view can be rendered inside a parent, possibly even recursively though I wouldn't recommend that! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your editor template is named incorrectly. There are two ways for MVC to pick it up:

**By Name**

Name the template with the exact same name as the data type:

```
DateTime.cshtml
String.cshtml
AdditionalUser.cshtml
```

**Explicitly**

In the property of your model, use the `UIHint` attribute:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public SomeObject TheObject { get; set; }

    [UIHint("SomeObject")]
    public SomeObject AnotherObject { get; set; }

}
```

Additionally your code is not quite correct to get the rows rendered. You should first add the `tr` tag to the view:

```
@model MyProject.Models.AdditionalUser

<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Surname)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Cost)
    </td>
</tr>
```

Next change your parent view to something like this (note I've added table header row for clarity):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.FirstName)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Surname)</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Cost)</th>
    </tr>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdditionalUsers)
</table>
```

Comment: After renaming the view to AdditionalUser.csthml I still do not see the rows rendered at all?

Answer (score 1):

You can drop the "_" character from the name, or there is an overload, that takes a template name as the second argument.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdditionalUsers, "_AdditionalUsers")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your GET action method, you need to return some item in the `AdditionalUsers` collection. Try this.

```
var yourViewModel=new YourViewModel();

var userList =  new List<AdditionalUser>();
userList.Add(new AdditionalUser { FirstName ="A"} );
userList.Add(new AdditionalUser{ FirstName ="B"});

yourViewModel.AdditionalUsers =userList();
return view(yourViewModel);
```

Also your **editor template name should be same as the class name** which is strongly typed to the editor template razor view, which is `AdditionalUser.cshtml`

Answer (score 0):

here is the rules

1- the name of the template must be same. in your case it must be AdditionalUser.cshtml
2- MVC first looks if a folder **EditorTemplates** exists in the parent folder of the view (which has controller name) then looks at Shared folder.

But in your case `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.AdditionalUsers)` is would not work as the type is List and as far as I know there is no way to do that so use a foreach loop;

```
@foreach (var u in model.AdditionalUsers) {
    @Html.EditorFor(model => u)
}
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Not strictly true, MVC does pick up `List<AdditionalUser>` and render it as multiple `AdditionalUser` views.